# Change the placement property of the all the sheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the placement property of all the `ChartObjects` and shape in my workbook.

However I am getting a Run-Time error

> requested shapes are locked for selection

on this line:

```
 cht.Select
```

Please find below the code:

```
Sub LoopThroughCharts()
'PURPOSE: Loop through every object in the active workbook

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim shp As Shape

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet
'Retrieve Input from User
PropertyOption = Application.InputBox("Change Everything To What Placement Property?" & _
"(Must be 1, 2, or 3)" & vbCr & vbCr & "   [1] Move and Size with Cells" & vbCr & _
"   [2] Move but Don't Size with Cells" & vbCr & "   [3] Don't Move or Size with Cells" & _
vbCr & " ", Type:=1, Title:="Placement Property For All")

'Handle If User Cancels
If PropertyOption = 0 Then Exit Sub

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
        If cht.Visible = True Then
            cht.Select
            cht.Placement = PropertyOption
            'Do something with the chart...
        End If
    Next cht
Next sht

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each shp In sht.Shapes
        If shp.Visible = True Then
            shp.Select
            shp.Placement = PropertyOption
        End If
    Next shp
Next sht

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You must have some protected worksheet. You cannot select or manipulate shapes in a protected worksheet, unless you allow the option "Edit Objects" when porotecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `Select` the `Cht` in order to modify it's properties.

Almost never you will need to `Select` or `Activate` in order to modify a property or a value, the only think "it does" is slow your code's run-time.

Just use:

```
For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each Cht In Sht.ChartObjects
        If Cht.Visible = True Then
            Cht.Placement = PropertyOption
            'Do something with the chart...
        End If
    Next Cht
Next Sht
```

Comment: If the sheet is protected, which I suspect, it wont allow to modify the placement.

Comment: Its working now, thank you. Just one last question in case I dont want it to be applied in all the worksheets but just few worksheets which I have selected then how should I modify the code as my selected sheet can differ so I cannot specify the names of the worksheets

Comment: @Stacey then you need to loop through the sheets and see which ones are `Selected` - I think it's an excellent new **SO** post

Comment: Sure I am posting a new post for this